# Can a caller abort an execution of code invoked by HTTP request?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net, http, asp.net-core

A third party that is going to make HTTP requests to the API that I'm building, requires that the API responds in less than one second. My question is, do they have a way (literally *any* way, within the bounds of the http and/or tcp/ip protocols) to abort the execution of my code if it takes longer than one second?

Comment: They can set the timeout of the HttpClient directly, but that does not abort the code running on the server side.

Comment: Yes. IP geolocation and a cruise missile. If that's not what you had in mind, you will have to get a *lot* more precise with your "literally any way".

Comment: There could tens reasons that could "make belive" the user that the process is taking longer than 1 second. For example, latency. You know, someone in the office downloading suspicious content... By the time the user send the cancel request, the process could have finished successfully. 1 second is to little time (I think) for a human.

Comment: @jmoreno does your "bounds" include me adding a cancel button for the user to click? Or are you looking for something lower in the osi stack than the application layer?

Comment: Surprised this was VTC'd actually. The answer is *sure.* Nothing prevents you from registering requests in some way and adding an endpoint or API method that cancels them -- either through native process management or by having "cancellable" requests periodically check if they've been instructed to stop...

Comment: @candied_orange: I understood the OP to be asking if the client can do anything on their end that doesn’t involve interfering with the physical operation of the server so no going to the server and unplugging it or blowing up the city the server is in as at least one person commented, without his cooperation.  I’m sure he realizes it would be possible to enable them to do something that would effectively allow them to cancel the process if he wanted to....

Comment: ...the question as I read it is whether the client can do anything like pull the plug on their end close a browser window or send an abort for an already sent request which would cause the server to stop executing his without him somehow enabling that.

Comment: @jmoreno well you got my vote to reopen. Might need to take this to meta.

Answer (score 12):

HTTP doesn't work like that. The client sends a request, then the server sends a response back. No other communication occurs. Well, the server can send 1xx informational responses before the main response. But there is no way for the client to send updates about a sent request.

(The situation is very different for HTTP/2 which can multiplex multiple requests over the same connection. A client can CANCEL a stream to indicate that it is no longer needed after it receives a PUSH_PROMISE from the server. I'll ignore HTTP/2 for the rest of this answer.)

Also, networks don't work like that. In particular, see the second [fallacy of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing): “latency is zero”. It is not. Of that one second timeout, 400ms may have been spent on establishing the connection and sending the request and 600ms on the response, because one of the packets was dropped and you had to resend everything and your client is in Australia. Aside from the problem that the server might not have enough time, the server doesn't even know how much time they have because response latency cannot be known in advance.

So given that literally implementing these timeouts is impossible, what kind of solution might be good enough?

If the response will have no value after the timeout, the client can simply close the connection. This will cause your response to be ignored, but will not prevent the response.

Closing the TCP connection over which the HTTP request is sent does notify the server. But this notification only arrives with latency, so it may be too late. Also, your web framework may not be doing anything when the client socket is closed. In that case you'd only get an error “connection reset by peer” once you try to write to the closed socket.

If you do not want to spend more than one second on processing for the response, implementing that timeout is entirely your responsibility, and has nothing to do with networking or HTTP.

You can ask the client to provide a timeout to the server, so that the server can abort if it cannot meet the deadline. This could be specified as a custom header, or as a query parameter in the URL. This deadline should be an absolute point in time and not a duration so that transmission delays also consume the available time. But sub-second accuracy is difficult: the server and the client need to be synchronized with the correct time and need to use a suitable clock. Depending on the setup each time source may be off by 100ms even when configured correctly. This already eats a significant chunk of your time budget.

Comment: Of course you can send a timeout as relative time - it just means the server cannot stop processing x seconds after you send the request, but only x seconds after the server received it. May be better if you cannot guarantee that your clock and the server clock are the same. If they are two minutes apart, _all_ requests with a one minute timeout (in absolute time) might be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose they could close the connection, but I don't know if that would actually cause your code to abort - it would depend on how your code is written.

They could also send another message that could mean "you're taking too long so don't bother" but in that case, you'd probably already be prepared to handle an explicit CANCEL_REQUEST message.

Comment: I think writing to a closed port will signal, but you can of course ignore or handle that signal (I only know this from the client side, where this problem would make the client crash if you don't handle it). Apart from that, the client cannot FORCE the server to do anything. Of course the server can abort its work voluntarily if the port is closed, or abort work if it's not going to be done within the timeout, or abort work if the client sends a message to cancel the request.